# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128) chinese characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Im trying to write Chinese characters into a text file from a SQL output called `result`. 
`result` looks like this:
 `[('你好吗', 345re4, '2015-07-20'), （'我很好',45dde2, '2015-07-20').....]`

This is my code:

```
#result is a list of tuples
    file = open("my.txt", "w")
    for row in result:
        print >> file, row[0].encode('utf-8')
    file.close()
```

`row[0]` contains Chinese text like this: `你好吗`

I also tried:

`print >> file, str(row[0]).encode('utf-8')`

and

`print >> file, 'u'+str(row[0]).encode('utf-8')`

but both gave the same error.

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: can you show here the my.txt file please?

Comment: my.txt is an empty file which i am trying to write into

Answer (score 3):

Found a simple solution instead of doing encoding and decoding by formatting the file to "utf-8" from the beginning using codecs.

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open("my.txt", "w", "utf-8")
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to ad the UTF8 BOM on the file beginning if you wish to view your file in text editor correctly:

```
file = open(...)
file.write("\xef\xbb\xbf")
for row in result:
    print >> file, u""+row[0].decode("mbcs").encode("utf-8")
file.close()
```

I think you'll have to decode from your machines default encoding to unicode(), then encode it as UTF-8.

mbcs represents (at least it did ages a go) default encoding on Windows.

But do not rely on that.

Did you try the codecs module?

Comment: just did! see my answer :)

Comment: By "text editor" you only refer to Notepad, because virtually all the others handle UTF-8 without BOM just fine.

Comment: Most of them do assume that if BOM is not present they should use UTF-8. Some of them even can guess the encoding.  But not all. I saw gedit displaying UTF-8 as ASCII, even Text Edit under Mac. See, the problem is that applying UTF-8 or ASCII on a *.txt file is correct either way. It's only us making a fuss about seeing odd characters on the screen. But we cannot tell the user, now learn that those two characters means this one. Can we? Add a BOM and everything is safe and standardized. Using codecs produces file with a BOM.